# Can Drupal terms in different Taxonomies be synonymous?

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

Let's say

> **Taxonomy_A** is associated to **Node_Type_A**
>   **Taxonomy_B** is associated to **Node_Type_B**.
>
> AND
>
> Both **Taxonomy_A** and **Taxonomy_B** have a **term** called '**yellow**'.

Is it possible to make terms '**yellow**' synonymous, so that if I'm looking at a list of '**yellow**' stuff, I'm seeing content of both types (**Node_Type_A**, and **Node_Type_B**)?

#### Progress:

Unfortunately **it is not possible** for taxonomy terms to behave in Drupal as described in my question (at least not without forcing it):

It is clear by taking a look at the terms_related table that it would be possible to create paths that forced related terms together using the `taxonomy_get_related` function regardless of what vocabulary the term belongs to:

[image]

However, the way to get to these terms is through the `taxonomy_get_related` function in the taxonomy module. This function is not used at all in drupal-6 core except to define it.  (I did find it once in the ctools module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrong. I mean using taxonomy wrong, not technically, but as a concept. Ask yourself why do you have 2 vocabularies with term yellow? Both are colour. they belong to same dictionary. Maybe tell little more of what you are trying to make.

Maybe you need to change setup so you don't associate one dictionary to one content type, maybe CCK, views and this module can do what you need http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy

Comment: That's a good point.  The challenge came around because I imported some Wordpress blogs into Drupal, and the import module created two Taxonomies (one called Categories and another called Tags).  But I am also thinking of adding Tags to the blog node that I create which could have terms that are the same as from the imported Vocabulary.  And I want to make sure that if a term in one my tags is chosen the other imported nodes will also show up.  But I do understand your point.

Comment: maybe taxonomy manager module can help you manage or migrate and fix those tags and categories, but i don't remember if it worked across dictionaries