# Can Drupal Taxonomy module be used to categorize court records and briefs?

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

I'm currently working on a project that involves moving a database of documents for court records and briefs over to a Drupal environment.  One of the problems that we are faced with is how to index these documents.

In our court district, records and briefs all have a docket number which is assigned to a case.  The interesting thing is that when multiple cases merge the docket numbers associated to the case become synonymous:

> **Case 1**, documents have **Doceket No. A**
>
> **Case 2**, documents have **Docket No. B**
>
> If case **Cases 1** and **Case 2** merge, then **Docket No. A** = **Docket No. B**

My first inclination is to create a **Docket Vocabulary** and have the terms of this Taxonomy be the docket numbers.  I am hoping to take advantage of the fact that terms can be synonymous.

I understand that there are several functions in the Taxonomy module that I may be able to take advantage of, including:

```
taxonomy_get_synonyms
taxonomy_get_related
```

But I'm having problems convincing my colleagues that this is the way to go, and frankly I'm not certain it's the right solution either.  (Though one advantage I think is likely is that using Taxonomy in this way means we could take advantage of other taxonomy manipulating modules down the line).

If anyone has had a similar issue and can offer some guidance as to how to move forward, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

D

I've asked a related question (which I would also need to answer in order to move forward with this solution):

[Can Drupal terms in different Taxonomies be synonymous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656247/can-drupal-terms-in-different-taxonomies-be-synonymous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case for [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck). The Integer field type, most likely. If the dockets merge, edit the node, change the number. Revision history is tracked.

If you want to get fancy with the Docket Merging procedure, you will want to learn

1. How to create a custom Action.
2. How to use the [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module.
3. Possibly, [how to programmatically invoke the Bulk Operation via Rules](http://nodeone.se//blogg/johan-falk/make-rules-dance-with-views-bulk-operations).

It is a complex, but not difficult task, meaning there's a bunch to learn, but after that it shouldn't take long.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree that CCK is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

**Trying to use the taxonomy module (and it's related counterparts) to force this behavior is just not a good idea.**

Taxonomies are intend to bring some form of **order** and **meaning** to the content.

A vocabulary of thousands of terms that consists of numbers is just not a taxonomy.

When I took a closer look at the taxonomy module code, I decided that although I could probably force the behavior I'm seeking, taxonomies are not intended to be used to solve problems of this nature.

Also, the use of `taxonomy_get_synonym` as proposed in my question is plain wrong.  Taking a look at the table were synonym relationships are kept in drupal-6 we see that that synonyms are not terms.

[image]

Though, there is the possibility of coming up with a similar solution using the related terms, this would be foolhardy.